# Spreadsheet Like Layout Using UICollectionView

Tags: ios

How can I use UICollectionView to create a spreadsheet like layout where each row displays properties of a single object.

Example:

```
Customer Id   First Name   Last Name   Social  Address  Phone
```

Here is what I came up with using UITableView:

```
funds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    columnNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fundNumber",@"fundName",@"unitPrice",@"fundBalance",@"percentageOfAccountValue",@"futureContributionAllocation", nil];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FundCell"];

    Fund *fund = [funds objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    for(NSString *columnName in columnNames)
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 100, 44)];

        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        label.text = [fund valueForKey:columnName];

        x += label.bounds.size.width;

        [cell addSubview:label];

    }

    x = 0;

    return cell;
}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you'd be able to adapt the standard flow layout - you might need to create your own `UICollectionViewLayout` class - but this should be fairly straightforward to do.

Like a table view, your collection view can have sections and items: each row of your spreadsheet could be a section, and then the individual elements (Last Name, Social, Address, etc) could be items.

If you want *true* spreadsheet like functionality (i.e, you can scroll both horizontally *and* vertically) then you're going to have to build your own layout class. Otherwise you may be able to adapt the existing flow layout, although arguably if you *don't* need to scroll you could basically achieve what you're after with a table view instead.

Comment: Thanks! I only need to scroll vertically. I will check out UITableView maybe I will be able to utilize that instead of collection view.

Comment: I love collection views, but if you don't need horizontal scroll then you may find it easier to use a `UITableView`. Plus you'll have the benefit of being able to support iOS 5 (if you want).

Comment: The main issue I was facing was that I need a separate collection with all the properties that need to be displayed in columns like firstname, lastname etc. Also I need to dynamically create labels and then add it to the UITableViewCell with x spacing increasing.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the layout of a `UICollectionViewController` using the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` The idea behind what you want to do is this:
each column can be a section 
each title will be the header for each section.

For your example:
`– numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:` = 6 (Customer Id, First Name, Last Name, Social, Address, Phone) 
`– collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` = number of rows