# How to create a table like spreadsheet in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I needed to create table spreadsheets like excel. And they will be in a TableViewController's cells. So there will be multiple spreadsheets in different cells. Example:

[image: Example spreadsheet]

My first approach was to create nested UICollectionViews. However it slowed the UI heavily. It seems like using UICollectionView is bad for performance. This is how I implemented it anyway:

```
        let table = UIStackView()
        table.axis = .Vertical
        table.spacing = 8

        let json = JSON(data: jsonNew)

        for i in 0..<json["Rows"].count{

            let horizontal = UIStackView()
            horizontal.axis = .Horizontal
            horizontal.spacing = 8

            for j in 0..<json["Rows"][i]["Column"].count{

                let label = UILabel()
                label.text = json["Rows"][i]["Column"][j].string!
                label.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
                label.numberOfLines = 0
                label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(12)
                horizontal.addArrangedSubview(label)

            }

            table.addArrangedSubview(horizontal)

        }

        parent.addSubview(table)
        return table
```

The question is, is there any other way to implement this kind of table in a better way?

Comment: you are talking about nested collectionviews but use stackviews in your code sample. why don't you just use ONE collectionview?

Comment: One collectionview for all labels? How do I align them?

Comment: please check this library . may be it will be helpful for you. https://github.com/badalpub1991/BASReport

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A stack of collection views constructed like in your example would have terrible performance because you eagerly construct the whole hierarchy – there's vertically no cell reuse based on where your screen is in a potentially very tall table.

A custom collection view layout would strike as one natural way to accomplish this. Perhaps the code in [KEZCollectionViewTableLayout](https://github.com/ketzusaka/KEZCollectionViewTableLayout) could work as inspiration? There's also [MMSpreadsheetView](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMSpreadsheetView).

You may also find [this blog post](https://www.credera.com/blog/mobile-applications-and-web/building-a-multi-directional-uicollectionview-in-swift/) interesting.

(There is a related question on how to specifically accomplish this [using UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861450/spreadsheet-like-layout-using-uicollectionview).)

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You can read about how to interoperate between the two for instance here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/

Comment: You can also refer this library . https://github.com/badalpub1991/BASReport